# empty Edit Text gives me error for 0 value

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a project and I have problem with my addition for empty EditText( unused) . If I enter a number in my editText then click the button it will show the output in the viewtext (which is right) also if you keep doing that the number will be added to the total number .

BUT !! if I click the button without enter any number in my edittext . the project will be crashed showing the project has stopped !

What I want is : if I just click the button without enter any number the 0 will be added to the total number .  ex.. 5 >> Button >> 5+0=5 show 5 for total >> 6 >> Button >> 6 + 5= 11 >> **0 >> Button >> 0 + 11 = 11  (<< KEY)**

My code

```
MyActivity.java

    package b3du.im.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    int total = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    public void Add(View v){

        TextView text1 =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        EditText  text2 =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);


        int valueText2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());

        total= Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString());

        total += valueText2;

        text1.setText(Integer.toString(total));

        text2.setText("");

    }

}
```

activity_my.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:hint="0"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="Add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: as pointed out in the answers you need to check text2 to be null, and if it is, set it to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter nothing you get a blank in 
`text2.getText().toString()` and you get a NumberFormatException.

You should set `valueText2 to 0 if no text is entered:

```
int valueText2 = 0;

if (text2.getText() != null && !text2.getText().toString().equals("")){
   int valueText2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: thanks now my project works fine .. the code makes it easy for me to understand

Comment: If you can answer this , can you tell me how to do this code by other way than using If statement like (try) ?

Comment: I think `if` is the best solution. I think i tis not a good idea to make it with try. But if you want to it you can d it this way: `try{
    valueText2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
int valueText2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());
```

If the string is empty, parseInt will throw an exception.  You need to check if its empty first and not vall parseInt.

Also, in the future always post the stack trace from logcat for a crash.  It tells you exactly what the error is.